# Add 24 hours in Firebase Server Timestamp while storing it in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello Android Programmers out there.
I need a little help from you guys.
I am creating an app and I am feeling confused in a function where I want to add 24 hours in Timestamp value which has been stored in the form of ASCII long in firebase database. 
So I want to ask that how to store two values in Firebase Database one with Timestamp and other with Timestamp + 24 hours.

```
newPost.child("post_time").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
newPost.child("post_time + 24 hours").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP + "what should i do here");
```

Comment: You can't do this on the client.  Instead you could write a Cloud Function to do the math using the local time on the Cloud Functions server.